# Repeat shape and add it as a Layout background

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following drawable, which is an inverted triangle, that I want to draw multiple times, to simulate a zigzag. Something similar to this:

[image]

**inverted_triangle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:width="32dp"
  android:height="24dp"
  android:viewportWidth="32.0"
  android:viewportHeight="24.0">
  <path android:fillColor="#0E17B1"
    android:pathData="M0 0 h32 l-16 24 Z"/>
</vector>
```

[image]

I tried using the following:

**repeat_bg_triangle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:src="@drawable/inverted_triangle"
  android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

And adding it to a layout like this:

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/repeat_bg_triangle" />
```

But it's not working. Any ideas on how can I achieve it using only XML?

Comment: it would be easier if you just use custom drawing. You can take a look at the below code to have an idea about how to draw. The code is in Dart/Flutter but the mechanism remains the same in Native Android https://github.com/umuieme/FlutterClipperFun/blob/master/lib/custom_clipper/zigzag.dart

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is create vector file `inverted_triangle.xml` with multiple inverted triangle inside.